# Android Studio: How to access project level compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion in Kotlin Multiplatform shared module build.gradle.kts?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to add a KMM shared module to my existing Android Studio project. I would like to use the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion from project level build.gradle in the shared module, but I can't seem to use it.

Here's the code snippet from shared module *build.gradle.kts*:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion(30) // I want to use a project-wide variable here instead of '30'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(23) // And here
        targetSdkVersion(30) // And here
    }
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `Dependencies/Versions` file in your `buildSrc` to specify versions, that can be reused by multiple modules.

For an example see https://github.com/joreilly/PeopleInSpace/blob/master/buildSrc/src/main/java/Dependencies.kt